# JQuery find() method on the ajax response returns null

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a problem with my ajax request :

```
    $.ajax({
        url: sAjaxPageUrl,
        context: document.body,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {

                    var response = $(data).find("#content").html();

                    response = "<div class=\"popupInner2\"><form action =\"#\" class=\"calledForm\" method=\"post\">"+response+"</form></div><span class=\"clear\">&nbsp;</span>";
                                    $(this).easyPopup({
                                        sHtml: response
                                    })
                                    submitForm();


        }
    });
```

the page loaded is:

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
    body {background:url('images/content/logo_exclamation.jpg') no-repeat scroll 0 35px #dfe0e2;}
    #content {padding-left: 126px;padding-top: 15px;}
    #paragraph {color:#314395;font:14px/1.3em Arial;width:auto;margin: 7px 0 0;}
    #intro {color:#314395;font:18px Arial;margin-bottom: 0;}
    #thirdPartyCookies {padding-right: 10px;}
</style>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="thirdPartyCookies">
    <div id="content">
        <p id="intro">
            This feature has been disabled.
        </p>
        <p id="paragraph">We are unable to show what's missing here.<br>
        You can change this easily in your <a href="/cookies_settings/cookies_settings.aspx" target="_blank">Cookie settings</a>.
        </p>
    </div>

</div>

</body>


</html>
```

This works but i want to load the thirdPartyCookies div and when i write $(data).html(), it returns null...
(in short, i don't need to add find(), cause i'm already "on" the good element.

Thanks in advance for your help...

Comment: What does sAjaxPageUrl return?

Comment: Try this: var response = $('#content', $(data)).html();

Comment: it works but i want to load the parent element ! not content !Thx

Comment: use $('#content', $(data)).parent().html()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when parsing your html with jQuery, the `<body>` and the `<head>` and `<html>` tags are being stripped down (for obscure reasons) and the element you are trying to reach (`id="thirdPartyCookies"`) is at the root of your object.

`.find()` only search for descendant, so since your element is in the root, it will never find it. I have 2 suggestions for you.

You could use `.filter()` to get your element :

```
$(data).filter("#thirdPartyCookies").html();
```

But that will not work if your HTML change later and the `#thirdPartyCookies` is a children of something else.

To make it work no matter what's your HTML, create a new `div` and insert your content into it. You can then `.find` your element :

```
$('<div>').html(data).find("#thirdPartyCookies").html();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer but your first advice returns again the content div, not thirdPartyCookies ... very strange ...

Comment: @FieryA `.html()` will not return the selected `div` HTML (but its content). You probably want `("#thirdPartyCookies").prop('outerHTML');`

Comment: Very nice explanation, I don't know why this response wasn't upvoted!

Comment: `$('<div>').html(data).find("#thirdPartyCookies").html();` this is works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line.

```
var response = $(data).find('#thirdPartyCookies')[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: Thank you , but it returns null

Comment: Please add a rational to the code you posted, i.e. why does your suggestion work and why does the OP's code not.